# How does one access childCategory information for transactions?

Tags: yodlee

I am successfully pulling transactional data, but all transactions have a `categoryLevelId` of `3`. In the [`getUserTransactionCategories`](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getUserTransactionCategories) API, I see one item containing a `childCategory` block with items listed as `categoryLevelId: 4`.

How do I access user transactions with more in-depth categorization data? For example, I have a transaction with a `merchantName` of `"Dunkin' Donuts"`. This is a coffee shop, so I'd like to be able to differentiate this transaction from a dine-out restaurant.

I have tried a competing aggregator (Plaid). They have the same concept of supercategories, categories, and subcategories. These are the [categories](https://github.com/plaid/support/blob/master/categories.md) they support. Is there something like that with Yodlee?

Answer (score 0):

categoryLevelId:4 is a sub category created by the user.

This means user can create sub-categories under a specific category and re-categorize transactions to that specific category, Yodlee will learn that and onward transactions for that users having the same description keywords will be categorised.